# Unable to use regex or search on ansible task for a string search

Tags: regex, ansible

Team,

I have this task below where I want to create a condition and based on that I want to run other tasks. so as first step, creating condition task itself is failing because am not able to figure out the syntax.. ran several iterations and also check online here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html

Any hint, am new.

```
  - name: Identify device naming convention[nvme*] using REGEX
    debug:
      msg: "Found Block Device {{ item.0.device }}"
    loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
    #when: "{{ item.0.device }}" is regex("nvme2\w+"). #<<<FAILED
    when: "{{ item.0.device }}" is search("nvme")
    register: nv_device_type
    tags: tag_to_create_with_values, tag_to_delete
  - name: Output device from REGEX results
    debug:
      var: nv_device_type
    ignore_errors: no
```

output

```
   ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
     expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
   
   The error appears to be in '/ansible-managed/jenkins-slave/slave0/workspace/nvdc/run_ansible_playbook@2/k8s/baremetal/roles/local_volume_mount/tasks/main.yml': line 45, column 33, but may
   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
   
   The offending line appears to be:
   
       #when: "{{ item.0.device }}" is regex("nvme2\w+")
       when: "{{ item.0.device }}" is search("nvme")
                                   ^ here
   We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
   missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
   start a value. For instance:
   
       with_items:
         - {{ foo }}
   
   Should be written as:
   
       with_items:
         - "{{ foo }}"
```

my values are below

```
local_volume_mount_disks:
  - device: /dev/nvme2n1
    partitions:
      - number: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out after several iterations..

```
  - name: Identify device naming convention[nvme*] using REGEX
    debug:
      msg: "Found Block Device {{ item.0.device }}"
    loop:  "{{ local_volume_mount_disks|subelements('partitions') }}"
    when: '"{{item.0.device }}" is search("nvme")'
    register: nv_device_type
```

output

```
 ok: [node1] => (item=[{'device': '/dev/nvmedn1', 'partitions': [{'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '100%'}]}, {'number': 1, 'start': '0%', 'end': '100%'}]) => {
      "msg": "Found Block Device /dev/nvmedn1"
  }
```